# Java : Get image as a BufferedImage from classpath

Tags: java, printing, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX project in which I have to print a few images for which I have the path. Now the problem is, I want to get the image as a BufferedImage and then call the print function which I have. How can I achieve this. Any help would be nice.

Code :

```
public void printThis(String localPath){

       // What should I do here? 

    System.out.println("Lets print this. ");
}


private void printImage(BufferedImage image) {
    java.awt.print.PrinterJob printJob = java.awt.print.PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintable(new Printable() {
        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            // Get the upper left corner that it printable
            int x = (int) Math.ceil(pageFormat.getImageableX());
            int y = (int) Math.ceil(pageFormat.getImageableY());
            if (pageIndex != 0) {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
            graphics.drawImage(image, x, y, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    });

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                printJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Edit :

Updated print function :

```
public void printImage(ImageView image) {
        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
        if (printJob != null) {
            boolean success = printJob.printPage(image);
            if (success) {
                printJob.endJob();
            }
        }
    }
```

The images are in classpath. Kindly let me know. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the images are in the classpath" and what the `localPath` parameter is in that context? Do you mean you are bundling the images with the jar file you create for your application?

Comment: @James_D : My project architecture is src-->Main.java(Print function here), src contains directory resources-->img-->abc.png. Now I want to print this abc.png

Comment: So the image is deployed relative to the classpath as `/img/abc.png`, or `/resources/img/abc.png`? Is that (`"/img/abc.png"` or `"/resources/img/abc.png"`) the value passed in as `localPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the parameter contains, but the basic idea is

```
public void printThis(String localPath) {
    try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(localPath);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
        printImage(image);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        // handle elegantly...
    }
}
```

This assumes `localPath` contains the name of the resource as defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html), either relative to the current class (but note that all components of the path must be valid Java identifiers, so no `..`, etc), or absolute (i.e. relative to the classpath) if it begins `/`.

Since you are writing a JavaFX project, though, it surely makes more sense to use JavaFX APIs for this instead. Also note there's no need to do the printing on the FX Application Thread, and it's probably advisable not to. So you could do

```
public void printThis(String localPath) {

    // note you can use overloaded forms of the Image constructor
    // if you want to scale, etc
    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource(localPath).toExternalForm());
    new Thread(() -> printImage(image)).start();
}

public void printImage(Image image) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (printJob != null) {
        // scale image if necessary by using imageView.setPreserveRatio(true)
        // along with imageView.setFitWidth(...) and imageView.setFitHeight(...)
        boolean success = printJob.printPage(imageView);
        if (success) {
            printJob.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The image is only for the top 25%, I would like to print the entire image. DO you know what I have to change in the printImage() method?

Comment: What do you mean? Is the image too big for the page?

Comment: No, the method above is scaling the image to 25% from top. So, if you divide the image in 4 parts, only one part is getting printed. I think the printImage code is doing that. WIth the graphics.DrawImage().

Comment: No clue why that is happening. BTW why are you using the AWT classes if this is a JavaFX project? Why not use `javafx.scene.image` and `javafx.print` APIs?

Comment: Any idea how I can print a BufferedImage using JavaFX api's then? Kindly let me know.

Comment: Why do you want a `BufferedImage`? Like I said, just use the JavaFX APIs. Create a` javafx.scene.image.Image` and `ImageView`, the print the `ImageView` using JavaFX print APIs.

Comment: Can you kindly come in chat. Just for conversion of path to image which I can call with print. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100783/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-james-d).

Comment: Thank you, but the image is not fitting the paper, it's still getting only 25-30%. How can I instruct to fit to XY? Any idea? I am using an A4 paper for printing.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible for me to answer that without knowing details about the image. But basically, scale the image so it fits. You can do that when you load the image (or in the imageView). You can get information about the size of the page and the resolution from the print job using `getPageLayout()` and `getPrintResolution()`. Just read the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html), it is all pretty obvious.

Comment: Hello, Just one last thing. After reading docs, I have created a PageLayout associated with printer. I just want to know how to inform that to the job. Can you please check the updated code at bottom of the main post. Thank you.. :-)

Comment: I think you can just do `PageLayout pageLayout = printJob.getJobSettings().getPageLayout();` to get the default layout. Or you should be able to do `printJob.getJobSettings().setPageLayout(...)` to change the layout if you need.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out so much. The problem of image scaling I have started as a new thread at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815660/javafx-image-getting-scaled-to-25-and-then-getting-printed . Kindly have a look when you have time. Thank you. :-)