# JavaFX : Image getting scaled to 25% and then getting printed.

Tags: java, image, printing, javafx, image-scaling

I am trying to print an image using JavaFX api's. Unfortunately, it is cutting a part of the image, approximately 25% and then stretching that to the entire A4 page, and printing it. What am I doing wrong with the print code. How can I instruct to fit the image to page for printing, no matter what the printer is. Kindly let me know.

Code :

```
 public void printThis() {

        System.out.println("I was called");
        // note you can use overloaded forms of the Image constructor
        // if you want to scale, etc
        String path = "resources/img/printouts/image.png";
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource(path).toExternalForm());
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        new Thread(() -> printImage(imageView)).start();
    }

    public void printImage(ImageView image) {
        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
        PageLayout pageLayout = printJob.getJobSettings().getPageLayout();
        //PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
        printJob.getJobSettings().setPageLayout(pageLayout);
        if (printJob != null) {
            boolean success = printJob.printPage(image);
            if (success) {
                printJob.endJob();
            }
        }
    }
```

Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong. Thank you. :-)

Comment: BTW: The `if` check statement doesn't do anything useful there: The condition is always true after the previous line is (successfully) executed.

Comment: And the previous line does nothing, given the line before it...

Comment: Now I'm at a printer, I tested the solution @fabian posted, and it does seem to work. I'm not really sure why, but maybe there are things about printing resolution I don't understand.

Comment: @james_d yes.. I spent around an hour trying to resolve this... No luck unfortunately... Finally i will look into the location independent resource access tomorrow i.e jan 16 2016.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The solution @fabian posted and then deleted (perhaps after my misleading comment) works just fine. Just do `image.setPreserveRatio(true);`, `image.setFitWidth(pageLayout.getPrintableHeight());` and `image.setFitWidth(pageLayout.getPrintableWidth());`. I'll let him reinstate his answer.

Comment: @James_D: No I didn't just delete the answer because of that comment. It somehow worked until I chose a different resolution i.e. 72dpi instead of 600dpi for PDFCreator in my case and suddenly the result was only 12% the size of the desired output... (for some reason the margin in the result did the same...) Therefore I cannot assume the solution works for all printers...

Comment: @james and fabian : why are the results of these libraries so vague.. Is it in beta or something? I thought this is like version 3 of fx...

Comment: It's not beta... At least it's not supposed to be... After all it's included in the JDK. However there are still some bugs to be squashed... E.g. I recently reported a bug that where the calling `listIterator().nextIndex()` returns `1` on some of the properties of a selection model (facepalm). Obviously that class wasn't tested thoughly enough. Shouldn't be a problem, right? Who uses that method after all? Well the programmers of `FilteredList` did... Let's say I was a bit more enthusiastic when I started using JavaFX...

Comment: It's 1. not a high priority (bear in mind Oracle is almost entirely concerned with server-side software, and additionally there are just not that many people writing thick-client apps these days). Some of it's excellent (the concepts behind the properties API, for example, even if there are some gaps in the library), and some (e.g. Charts) just looks like it was written by an intern without supervision. And then 2. it's not really fair to consider it v3: 2.0 was basically a complete re-write from scratch (so v1) and this version was just released along with Java8. Think 2.x beta and 8.x v1.

Comment: @james then why do they even bother.. Anyways swing exists(with serious drawbacks) ... I am actually interested in embedded projects, but more acquianted with java

Comment: Can't answer that :). I haven't messed with embedded. Despite the bugs, I find FX better than Swing as it just supports more modern design principals more readily.

Comment: @WeareBorg You want to run the code in Java SE Embedded? This is not supported! Look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/headful.htm#CIHBIBEI

Comment: @fabian : Can you repost your answer. I would still like to give it a try.

Comment: @WeareBorg: Done (i.e. undeleted); Also made it community wiki, since I do not have time do research the topic thoroughly enough right now...

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following code to the `printImage` method:

```
image.setPreserveRatio(true);
image.setFitHeight(pageLayout.getPrintableHeight());
image.setFitWidth(pageLayout.getPrintableWidth());
```

This will print the image scaled to the largest size that can be fit into a rectangle of `pageLayout.getPrintableWidth()` x `pageLayout.getPrintableHeight()` preserving the ratio, see [`ImageView.preserveRation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#preserveRatioProperty).

Comment: Do the units work correctly for that? (I'm just interested...) [`PageLayout.getPrintableHeight()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PageLayout.html#getPrintableHeight--) and `getPrintableWidth()` report the dimensions in units of 1/72 inch. Presumably the `image` dimensions are in pixel units. So do you have to account for print resolution, or does this just work?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right, you want to print an image on a arbitrary printer in any orientation, paper size, etc. And the image should not be cropped or changed by it's ratio, but it should be filled as much of the paper it can? Is that correct?

So, I've made a cheap example of how you are able to do it. You need to scale the image in widht and height, but both scale values should be the same (preserve ratio). You need the printable area of the printer (with default paper size) and then you will be able to calculate the correct values.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.print.PageLayout;
import javafx.print.Printer;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImagePrint extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Image image = new Image("https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/93337/road08.png");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        new Thread(() -> printImage(imageView)).start();
    }

    public void printImage(Node node) {

        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.getDefaultPageLayout();
        System.out.println("PageLayout: " + pageLayout);

        // Printable area
        double pWidth = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth();
        double pHeight = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight();
        System.out.println("Printable area is " + pWidth + " width and "
                + pHeight + " height.");

        // Node's (Image) dimensions
        double nWidth = node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
        double nHeight = node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
        System.out.println("Node's dimensions are " + nWidth + " width and "
                + nHeight + " height");

        // How much space is left? Or is the image to big?
        double widthLeft = pWidth - nWidth;
        double heightLeft = pHeight - nHeight;
        System.out.println("Width left: " + widthLeft
                + " height left: " + heightLeft);

        // scale the image to fit the page in width, height or both
        double scale = 0;

        if (widthLeft < heightLeft) {
            scale = pWidth / nWidth;
        } else {
            scale = pHeight / nHeight;
        }

        // preserve ratio (both values are the same)
        node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scale, scale));

        // after scale you can check the size fit in the printable area
        double newWidth = node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
        double newHeight = node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
        System.out.println("New Node's dimensions: " + newWidth
                + " width " + newHeight + " height");

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if (job != null) {
            boolean success = job.printPage(node);
            if (success) {
                job.endJob();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a Node to print. I have path of the file, which is a PNG image.

Comment: Simply put it in a node (ImageView), it doesn't have to be visible.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I will test this after configuring it and will get back to you.