# JavaFX 8 scale node for printing without changing displayed node

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX 8, I am printing a node (e.g., ScatterChart) with printerJob.printPage().  Without scaling, the printed node is cropped.  If I scale for printing, then the printed node is correctly fit to the page, but the displayed node is scaled.  A simple solution would be to make a copy/clone of the node, but it appears that isn't supported.  Is there a better solution than scaling the node and then removing the scaling (which causes the displayed node to briefly rescale, which is unsightly)?  It would seem that printing a graph would be a basic operation for JavaFX.

Comment: Hide the display node when printing. Bring it back when done.

Comment: I did try setVisible(false), but then it didn't print.  I suppose I could remove it from the parent node, print, then put it back into the parent node, but that is about as unsightly as the rescaling.  I'm still hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Snapshot` API? Then print the resulting image. [`SnapeShot`](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-snapshot-as-png-image/) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this app. It creates a PNG of the chart. It then prints the chart. I didn't scale the image. The actual image is located in your source folder. You can also open it using Paint and print from there. You can also code the printer settings so that the printer dialog shows up before printing.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication145 extends Application
{

    final static String itemA = "A";
    final static String itemB = "B";
    final static String itemC = "F";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final BarChart<Number, String> bc = new BarChart<Number, String>(xAxis, yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Value");
        xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
        yAxis.setLabel("Item");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, itemA));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, itemB));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, itemC));

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(50, itemA));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(41, itemB));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(45, itemC));

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(45, itemA));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(44, itemB));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, itemC));

        Button button = new Button("Print Chart");
        button.setOnAction((event)->{printImage(saveAsPng(bc));});//Create the image and print it.

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(bc);

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(button);
        vbox.getChildren().add(stackPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 800, 600);
        bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public File saveAsPng(BarChart barChart) {
        WritableImage image = barChart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

        // TODO: probably use a file chooser here
        File file = new File("chart.png");

        try {
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception here
        }

        return file;
    }

    private void printImage(File file) {
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        java.awt.image.BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printJob.setPrintable(new Printable() {
            @Override
            public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException                    {
                // Get the upper left corner that it printable
                int x = (int) Math.ceil(pageFormat.getImageableX());
                int y = (int) Math.ceil(pageFormat.getImageableY());
                if (pageIndex != 0) {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }
                graphics.drawImage(bufferedImage, x, y, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), null);

                return PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
        });
        try {
            printJob.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way the did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815660/javafx-image-getting-scaled-to-25-and-then-getting-printed) print job. They took the PNG and added it to an `ImageView`. Then they printed the `ImageView` using `JavaFX` printing API.

Comment: I will look at this when I get back to it.  I did try a similar approach with a snapshot of my JavaFX ScatterPlot before posting, but the quality resulting from my code was not as good as the quality resulting from scaling and printing the chart itself.  I did try to use a very high resolution image based on the printer resolution, but the result (with print to PDF) was inferior.  Probably, I did not use optimal parameters when creating the image.  It seems like the best way to do this would be for JavaFX to have optional scaling parameters provided to the PrinterJob.